# Multiple Selection Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to simulate a multiple selection scenario using Selenium webdriver, so that the user is able to select Item 1 and Item 5 (see the URL) .

URL [JQuery Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/)

Right now I am trying to do this using the **clickAndHold** function, but when I try, it selects all the other items in between the Item 1 and Item 5.

Right now this is happening

[image: This is happening]

I want this

[image: I want this]

My code goes like this :

```
baseUrl="http://jqueryui.com/selectable/";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable *"));
Actions act=new Actions(driver);

act.clickAndHold(list.get(0)).clickAndHold(list.get(4)).release().build().perform();
```

So the mouse is not released until it gets to the fifth item in the list, which probably is the reason for selection in between.

But If I try to not release the mouse click and select the fourth item, using this code

```
act.clickAndHold(list.get(0)).build().perform();
act.clickAndHold(list.get(4)).build().perform();
```

Then I'm getting the same output as the code above. What should I change here so the the items in between are not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you want is a more CTRL+click type of usage scenario, I'd recommend the following:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
       .click(list.get(0))
       .click(list.get(4))
       .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
       .build();
       .perform();
```

While I've not tested this exact code, this *should* get you down the right path.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is perfect. I am kinda lame for not thinking of this control thingy.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple options in the selectable:

```
List<WebElement> Selectable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='selectable']/*"));
Actions x = new Actions(driver);

x.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
 .click(Selectable.get(0))
 .click(Selectable.get(4))
 .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
 .build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());
        List<WebElement> credentials= getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("Your locator"]"));
        for (int i = 0; i <credentials.size() ; i++) {
        }
        actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(credentials.get(0))
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(credentials.get(4))
                .build().perform();
    }
```

That should help you to click on multiple options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).